# Gulp I need /dist to have node_modules and .git

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have folder structure like this

- dist
- src

  - public

    - index.html
    - main.js
  - server

    - server.js
- package.json
- Procfile
- .env
- .gitignore
- .git
- gulpfile.js
- node_modules

I need to upload /dist to Heroku and it requires git. And I need node_modules too in project. package.json on top includes express and socket.io depencencies and gulp as devDependencies. Should I upload whole thing to git and heroku or install just devDependencies in package.json on top and in /src create another package.json and node_modules and git and move it to /dist. I want /dist to be self-sufficient. But how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping this explanation will help you:

The /dist folder would be self-sufficient if you have a npm script to build your project to the dist folder and then the npm script **start** to run your application from this folder.

Another thing, the node_modules and the dist folder **[shouldn't](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#how-to-keep-build-artifacts-out-of-git)** go to any repository, since they're obtained from npm scripts (npm install and npm run build, in sequence).

Furthermore, as mentioned in their documentation, the "dependencies" part of package.json **must** include all the necessary packages to build your application

**Why's that so?**

*"After running the installation and [build steps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#build-behavior) Heroku will strip out the packages declared under devDependencies before deploying the application."* - Heroku Team

If you have any other question, reply here...

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, Heroku will run gulp once when uploaded, but you should put node_modules and dist in .gitignore to keep them out of git control, and if you've already committed them, you should run this command to each folder to remove them from git after updating the .gitignore: git rm --cached <folder>. Yes, another nodejs hosting services would most likely do the same, they may only differ on how they do the caching of node_modules dependencies ( Heroku does that based on package.json changes ). Yes, the src will take up space in storage and in the git tree, the node modules will take

Comment: Continuing... The node nodules will take space only in storage, but will be cached, and the dist will take space only in storage too, but won't be cached. And the last one, yeah will probably works just fine, I used to have an AngularJs app that used Gulp and Browser-sync and it worked very well without problems (: